# Gulp - not compile all Sass files and stops on Sass error

Tags: css, sass, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

This is my gulpfile.js, but I have 2 problems with it.

1) On every error from Sass (ex. I save variable before set it), watcher stops and I need to start it again. Is possible to fix this?
2) Sass compile not getting all files changes. What is bad here?

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
// var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin');
var rename = require("gulp-rename");
var runSequence = require('run-sequence');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();

/**
 * **********************
 * Developer Taks
 * **********************
 */
gulp.task('browserSync', function() {
    browserSync.init({
        server: {
            baseDir: 'public'
        },
    })
});

/*
 *  Bootstrap Sass
 * * * * * * * * * * *
 */
gulp.task( 'bootstrap-sass', function(){
    return gulp.src( 'dev/sass/bootstrap.scss' )
        .pipe( sass() )
        .pipe( rename( 'bootstrap.min.css' ) )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'public/assets/plugins/bootstrap/css' ) )
        .on('error', swallowError)
        .pipe( browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
});

/*
 *  Kopiowanie Bootstrap JS
 * * * * * * * * * * *
 */
gulp.task( 'copy-boostrap-js', function() {
    gulp.src( 'dev/js/bootstrap.js' )
    .pipe( rename( 'bootstrap.min.js' ) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( 'public/assets/plugins/bootstrap/js' ) );
});

/*
 *  Główny Sass
 * * * * * * * * * * *
 */
gulp.task( 'global-sass', function(){
    return gulp.src( 'dev/sass/**/*.scss' )
        .pipe( sass() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( 'public/assets/css' ) )
        .on('error', swallowError)
        .pipe( browserSync.reload({
            stream: true
        }))
});

/**
 * **********************
 * Production Taks
 * **********************
 */

/*
 *  Kopiowanie FullPage
 * * * * * * * * * * *
 */
gulp.task( 'copy-fullpage', function() {
    gulp.src( 'dev/components/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.min.css' )
    .pipe( rename( 'fullpage.min.css' ) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( 'public/assets/plugins/fullpage/css' ) );

    gulp.src( 'dev/components/fullpage.js/dist/jquery.fullpage.min.js' )
    .pipe( rename( 'fullpage.min.js' ) )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( 'public/assets/plugins/fullpage/js' ) );
});

/*
 *  Kopiowanie Swiper
 * * * * * * * * * * *
 */
gulp.task( 'copy-swiper', function() {
    gulp.src( 'dev/components/Swiper/dist/css/swiper.min.css' )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( 'public/assets/plugins/swiper/css' ) );

    gulp.src( 'dev/components/Swiper/dist/js/swiper.min.js' )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( 'public/assets/plugins/swiper/js' ) );
});

/**
 * ==================================================================================
 * ==================================================================================
 */

/**
 * Watch developer tasks
 *      gulp watch
 */                 // 
gulp.task( 'watch', [ 'bootstrap-sass', 'global-sass', 'copy-boostrap-js' ], function () {
    /* Bootstrap */
    gulp.watch( 'dev/js/bootstrap.js', [ 'copy-boostrap-js' ] ); 
    gulp.watch( 'dev/sass/bootstrap.scss', [ 'bootstrap-sass' ] ); 
    /* Main Sass */
    gulp.watch( 'dev/sass/**/*.scss', [ 'global-sass' ] ); 
    gulp.watch( 'public/*.html', browserSync.reload );
});

/**
 * Execute production tasks
 *      gulp build
 */
gulp.task( 'build', function() {
    runSequence(
        [ 'copy-fullpage', 'copy-swiper' ]
    )
});


function swallowError (error) {

  // If you want details of the error in the console
  console.log(error.toString())

  this.emit('end')
}
```

**EDIT:** Files of my project: https://mega.nz/#!W9Jm3ZKJ!oeGu9sTtLUKZ3bs4L0zv3ysFaOGs7ARIckGJZ0tRMzQ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need two tasks to build scss and to watch files.

[Build scss](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sass):

```
gulp.task('style:build', function () {
    gulp.src(path.src.style)
        .pipe(sass({errLogToConsole: true}))
        .pipe(cssmin())
        .pipe(gulp.dest(path.build.css));
});
```

String you need - `{errLogToConsole: true}` - show errors to console instead finishing work.

Watch [task](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-watch):

```
gulp.task('watch', function () {
    watch([path.watch.style], function (event, cb) {
        gulp.start('style:build');
    });
});
```

Where `path.watch.style` is `'src/style/**/*.scss'` - you need to write here the path to your source folder.

Watch task doesn't have any dependencies, so remove `[ 'bootstrap-sass', 'global-sass', 'copy-boostrap-js' ]`.

---

P.S. Remove `gulp.watch( 'dev/sass/bootstrap.scss', [ 'bootstrap-sass' ] );`. You have not to change anything at framework files. It's bad practice.

To customize bootstrap blocks you can override bootstrap [variables](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss) (if you want all buttons have `font-weight: bold;` you should override `$btn-font-weight` variable).
So, first import file with default variables. Then import file with your own variables. Finally import blocks you really need, for example navbar or greed.

You main scss file may look like:

```
@import "../bootstrap/scss/variables.scss"; 
@import "variables.scss"; // Put your custom variables in here 

@import "../bootstrap/scss/mixins.scss";

// Add navbar and greed from bootstrap
@import "../bootstrap/scss/navbar.scss"; 
@import "../bootstrap/scss/grid.scss";

// Add custom files here
@import 'custom.scss';
@import 'header.scss';
```

Main file sample found in Joseph Fitzsimmons [article](http://josephfitzsimmons.com/using-only-bootstrap-3s-grid-system-using-less/).

Comment: Thanks, I'll try this later. So how best to edit bootstrap components? In my own CSS normally overwrite this elements?

Comment: @Vertisan Bootsrap has a lot of variables. https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass/blob/master/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap/_variables.scss You can change them. For example, you import bootsrap files, then import you file with overrideing variables and then import bootsrap blocks and components you really need in your project.
So your main scss file may look like: `@import "bootstrap";  @import "my-custom-variables";  @import "bootstrap-grid";  @import "bootstrap-button";  @import "my-other-styles";`.

Comment: Good example is here http://josephfitzsimmons.com/using-only-bootstrap-3s-grid-system-using-less/

Answer (score 1):

I will not explain as you will **crystal clear** if you just see my **image**.

> Also You will get the **scss/sass error** in console

*Happy Programming !*

[image]

I used ***Gulp*** + ***Browser-sync*** + ***gulp-sass***

only this ***3*** package

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gulp-plumber` to catch the errors. Add `this.emit('end');` to the `handleError` function to keep the watch running

[Here's an article that covers it](http://blog.ibangspacebar.com/handling-errors-with-gulp-watch-and-gulp-plumber/)